# A problem about lub and glb of matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

For any matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, define $$lub_K(A):= \inf\{\alpha\geq 0: AK\subset \alpha K\},$$ and $$glb_K(A):= \sup\{\alpha\geq 0: \alpha K\subset AK\},$$ where $K$ is a equilibrated convex body.

Prove for any two matrices $R$ and $S$, if there exist $x$, not zero, such that $Rx=Sx$, then $glb_K(R)\leq lub_K(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathrm{glb}_K(R)=0$, there is nothing to show. Otherwise, let $y:=\eta_*x$ where $\eta_*:=\sup\{\eta:\,\eta y\in K\}$ (note that $\eta_*>0$ since $K$ contains interior points). Now if $\alpha K\subset RK$ for some $\alpha>0$, we have $\alpha y\in RK$. In addition, $\alpha y\in SK$ so for any $\beta>0$ such that $SK\subset\beta K$, $\alpha y\in \beta K$ and hence $\alpha\beta^{-1}y\in K$. But since $y$ is the largest scalar multiple of $x$ which "fits" into $K$, $\alpha\beta^{-1}\leq 1$ so we have $\alpha\leq\beta$ (that is, if $\alpha\beta^{-1}>1$, $\alpha\beta^{-1}y\not\in K$ by the definition of $y$).